# Import a module which has a dynamic module as dependency in nest.js

Tags: nestjs, nest-dynamic-modules

I'm newbie in `nest.js` and i'm trying to use a service from Q module in APP module.
Q module is importing a dynamic `BullModule` for Queue ...

q.module.ts

```js
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { join } from 'path';
import { QService } from './q.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'volume',
      processors: [
        {
          name: 'create',
          path: join(__dirname, 'vol.processor.js'),
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [QService],
})
```

app.module.ts

```js
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: !!ENV ? `.env.${ENV}` : '.env',
    }),
    BullModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        redis: {
          host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
          port: Number(configService.get('REDIS_PORT')),
          password: configService.get('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    IdentityModule,
    QModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    IdentityService,
    QService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Nest says:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the QService (?). Please make sure that the argument BullQueue_volume at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If BullQueue_volume is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If BullQueue_volume is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing BullQueue_volume */ ]
  })
```

How i can handle this?
I read some docs but i can't find :(

Comment: show us `QService`'s `constructor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than redefining `QService` in `AppModule`'s `providers`, `QModule` should have `QService` in **both** `providers` and `exports`. This will allow any module that `imports: [QModule]` to make use of the exports of `QModule` without needing to redefine the provider.

As a side note, every time you add a provider to the `providers` array of a module, that will be a new instance of said provider. In this case, there's two instances, and the `AppModule` wants access to everything `QService` needs. This is why you should use `exports` instead.